# Basic Java array coding, finding the largest number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Code to make an array, then sort it and return the largest number
Write a program in which the main method creates an array with 
10 slots of type int. Assign to each slot a randomly-generated 
integer. Call a function, passing it the array. The called
your main method. Your main method should display the number returned. 
Use a Random object to generate integers. Createwith

```
    Random r = new Random(7);
```

Generate a random integer with

```
    x = r.nextInt();
```

The code I have written so far

```
import java.util.*;

class Lab8Q6
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int list[] = new int[10];


        System.out.println(returnLargest(list));
    }

    public static int returnLargest(int a[])
    {
        Random r = new Random(7);
        for (int i=0; i <a.length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = r.nextInt();
            }
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return a[9];
    }

}
```

Comment: In java array are indexed from `zero` so for an array of `10` the last element will be at index 9

Comment: Also as `list` is defined in `main` then you will either have to pass that variable to the `returnLargest` or declare `list` as a `field`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I changed the code based on what you said, and although I don't think it's exactly what the question was asking precisely, it does the same job?

Comment: I think that you are required to populate your array with Random first, then pass it to your method.

Comment: Also, maybe you are required to iterate through your array finding the largest value

Comment: I think, like what @ScaryWombat said, you should populate the array in the main method first, then use the method to find the largest integer in the array. Also, you probably should change the `[9]` to something that can change with the size of the array, since it's not guaranteed to work with arrays with sizes other than 10.